# How to skip integration test in maven

Tags: maven, integration-testing

I am using apache maven, "-DskipTests" can only skip unit test, but for integration test, how can I skip it ? Does anyone know that ? Thanks

Answer (score 23):

Integration Tests are usually executed using the [failsafe-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/integration-test-mojo.html).

Depending on the version you are using there are two options: `skipTests` and `skipITs`. See [examples](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/examples/skipping-tests.html) on the plugin site.

Answer (score 7):

To skip running the tests for a particular project, set the skipITs property to true.

```
<project>
    [...]
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0-M6</version>
                <configuration>
                    <skipITs>true</skipITs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    [...]
</project>
```

You can also skip the tests via the command line by executing the following command:

```
mvn install -DskipTests
```

Since skipTests is also supported by the Surefire Plugin, this will have the effect of not running any tests. If, instead, you want to skip only the integration tests being run by the Failsafe Plugin, you would use the skipITs property instead:

```
mvn install -DskipITs
```

If you absolutely must, you can also use the maven.test.skip property to skip compiling the tests. maven.test.skip is honored by Surefire, Failsafe and the Compiler Plugin.

```
mvn install -Dmaven.test.skip=true
```

Answer (score 3):

It depends on which plugin you are using to execute your integration tests. I presume that you are talking about the integration test phase of [maven lifecycle](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html). As @wemu answered, this phase usually is run with the fail safe plugin, but you can use other plugins attached to this phase, like the [exec plugin](http://www.mojohaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/java-mojo.html).

Each plugin will (probably) have its own way to skip the tests. You can attach the `exec plugin` to the integration test phase this way:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.0</version>

            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>your execution id</id>
                    <phase>integration-test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>java</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
```

You would skip this plugin with the [parameter skip](http://www.mojohaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/java-mojo.html#skip) in the command lin

```
mvn integration-test -Dexec.skip
```

Note that this would skip all your exec plugin executions even if they are in other phases.